# How can I create new Resource in Moodle?

Tags: plugins, moodle

I have to create new `Resource` in **Moodle** (currently available resources are Book, File, Label etc). I know how to create an `activity module` in **Moodle**. I think both `activity` and `resource` are created in similar way. Then how can I align the newly created `resource` below the `RESOURCES` section(while adding the activity/resource in course).

[image]

Please help me to find any link/suggestion regarding to create `resources` in **Moodle**....

Answer (score 1):

In your plugin's `PLUGINNAME_supports function`, just return `MOD_ARCHETYPE_RESOURCE` when asked about feature `FEATURE_MOD_ARCHETYPE`.

See example at the start of the `mod/page/lib.php` file -https://github.com/moodle/moodle/blob/master/mod/page/lib.php